# How do I know if a window blocked by modal

Tags: qt, modal-dialog, qdialog

I have several modal dialogs and main dialog where I exec() modal. How do I know if a main window blocked by modal or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check if there is an active modal dialog with [QApplication::activeModalWidget()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qapplication.html#activeModalWidget).

Comment: I had write condition: QApplication::activeModalWidget() == NULL.